# Display pagination number on page title

Tags: pagination, twig, multilingual, shopware

Currently, I have an issue about display pagination title in Shopware, template use Twig, load pagination pages by ajax, multi languages use snippet.

Detail:

- The pagination title that need to be displayed: Page "X". X is page number.
- The site used multi languages site, ex: english (Page "X"), german (Seite "X") ...
- For default url (ex: abc.com/category-name) or page = 1 (ex: abc.com/category-name/?p=1): Not display pagination title.
- For other pages (page 2, 3, 4): Display Page 2 ...

Page items will be loaded by use ajax when click the page number.
So, I don't know what to do display the pagination title on page title with multi languages.

Can everyone help me to resolve this issue?
Thank everyone.

Answer (score 2):

You can hook into this method:

`ListingPaginationPlugin.onChangePage` (see the source code in `vendor/shopware/storefront/Resources/app/storefront/src/plugin/listing/listing-pagination.plugin.js`)

And after calling the parent method, insert - for a proof of concept - code like this:

```
    document.title = event.target.value;
```

This would simply show the page number in the title (but losing the original title)

I suggest you back-up the original title and just append the "Page X" / "Seite X" information to it according to your necessary logic.

Now you need the translated word for "Page" available in the Javascript code.

You could attach this as a data-attribute to the title tag in the according twig template and use the normal `|trans' filter. I am not sure if there is a better way to have translations available in Javascript code in Shopware, so [I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69956260/how-to-access-a-translation-in-javascript-of-the-shopware-6-store-front).