# How to access a translation in Javascript of the Shopware 6 store front?

Tags: javascript, translation, shopware, shopware6

How can a translations snipped (created like here: https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/add-translations) be accessed in Javascript code of the frontend?

What first comes to my mind is to print the translated string into some kind of hidden tag / data attribute within the twig file and then read it from the JavaScript code.

But is there a suggested way to do this?

EDIT: I am looking for examples on how the Shopware 6 core developers do this, to find a best-practice and not invent something own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need it once a page, you can add it into data-attribute within plugin-related element. Other way, especually recommended when you need it multiple time on an page to save content:

I personally like set these texts in a variable for the window. Just where other window-variable are set and request them within the plugin.

```
{% block base_script_router %}
{{ parent() }}
<script>
    window.contactTexts = {
        product: '{{ 'anySnippet'|trans|e('js') }}',
        basket: '{{ 'anySnippet'|trans|e('js') }}',
        order: '{{ 'anySnippet'|trans|e('js') }}',
        inkl: '{{ 'anySnippet'|trans|e('js') }}'
    };
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Are there examples in the Shopware 6 core on how they do it? I want to find a best-practice way and not invent something own :-)

Comment: They don't use translation for JS-plugins. But you have a look here for window-variable-assignment: https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/e95f8b5a70b6ec9d2263812aa1869960a81f01ff/src/Storefront/Resources/views/storefront/base.html.twig#L121-L133

This is the way we are using in one of our js-plugins:
https://pastebin.com/raw/KEPaCtdE

Then check if window.contactTexts exists for safety in your plugin, and then use it.

Comment: Neat! Mind copying the paste bin to your answer?