# Shopware 6 get the plugin translation text in store front using javascript

Tags: twig, shopware6

in shopware6 added custom plugin with json file
`{ "search": { "config": { "text": "testing" } } }`
how to get this testing text in JavaScript in my custom plugin tried set windows variables but it not working

Comment: "*tried set windows variables*" - Please add your attempts inside the question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69956260/how-to-access-a-translation-in-javascript-of-the-shopware-6-store-front?rq=2 @DarkBee like this i tried but not worked in 6.5 version

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing javascript variable inside {{ }} symfony twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43373097/accessing-javascript-variable-inside-symfony-twig)

Comment: this is in php i want in js my custom plugin

Comment: This is not in PHP, this is setting the variables in the twig template, which shopaware uses, which allows you to pass them to your javascript

Comment: but if i used in separate js how to get this within this twig this is ok

Comment: You can't access twig variables in an external JS file... You need to set them directly in the base template and then you can access the created JS variables in the external file

Comment: Maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37604063/twig-variable-in-external-js-file) makes more sense

Answer (score -1):

You have to set up your JS part like this in a template file.

```
<script>
    var myText = "{{ 'search.config.text'|trans }}";
    
    console.log(myText);
</script>
```

You can't directly use the snippets in a JS file.

Comment: but in separate js file how to get this myText value

Comment: `window.myText= "{{ 'search.config.text'|trans }}"; console.log(window.myText);`